# Inner join table a or b based on existence

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got these 3 tables:

**Table A**

```
---------------------------
|KEY | VALUE_A1 | VALUE_A2|
---------------------------
```

**Table B**

```
------------------------------
|KEY | APPLICATION | VALUE_B1|
------------------------------
```

**Table C**

```
------------------------------
|KEY | APPLICATION | VALUE_C1|
------------------------------
```

I want to return A.VALUE_A1, A.VALUE_A2 along with B.VALUE_B1 or C.VALUE_C1 based on the existence of the application in B or C. This application is given in de where-clause in de script.

Example:
Table A has 10 records. Table B contains 6 records with application 'APP1'. Table C contains 4 records with application 'APP2'. Both table B and C are through KEY connected to table A. If the application given is 'APP1' then I want to return B.VALUE_B1. If 'APP2' is given I want to return C.VALUE_C1.

Is it possible to INNER JOIN on one of two tables based on a CASE-like condition?

Comment: yes it is possible. Show what you have tried, your expected results and actual results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not INNER JOIN but LEFT JOIN like this

```
select A.KEY
       A.VALUE_A1, A.VALUE_A2,
       CASE WHEN B.VALUE_B1 IS NOT NULL THEN B.VALUE_B1 ELSE C.VALUE_C1 END AS RESULT_VALUE
from A
    LEFT JOIN B on A.key=B.key
    LEFT JOIN C on A.key=C.key
```

UPDATE: There is an alternative

```
select A.KEY
       A.VALUE_A1, A.VALUE_A2,
       sub.VALUE AS RESULT_VALUE
from A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT KEY, VALUE_B1 as VALUE
                FROM B
                UNION ALL
                SELECT KEY, VALUE_C1 as VALUE
                FROM C) sub on A.KEY=sub.KEY
```

Comment: Tip: `coalesce(B.VALUE_B1, C.VALUE_C1)` to save some typing.

Comment: @jarlh i know the function, than you) just wrote to easier understanding the idea.

Comment: @StanislavL your alternative was the solution to my problem. Thank you!